# EOFError: EOF when reading a line, can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I've been trying to make a python Among Us game (kinda I guess) but this error has been really annoying. Here is my code:

```
import random
print("Python Among Us")
print()
role = ["Crewmate", "Crewmate" , "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Crewmate", "Impostor"]
roleconfirmed = random.choice(role)
print("You are a", roleconfirmed, "!")
if roleconfirmed == ("Crewmate"):
    firstdestination = input("Where would you like to go? ")
```

Here is the exact error in the console:

```
Python Among Us

You are a Crewmate !
Where would you like to go? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    firstdestination = input("Where would you like to go? ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any ideas why this error still persists?

Comment: I tried your code and get no such error.

Comment: I think that the compiler I use is giving me the error though I do want to confirm it by others.

Comment: Are you running this online? You appear to have the STDIN set to something other than the terminal, and haven't supplied any data to it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am running it on an online compiler. I speculate that might be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewLiu So, somewhere on that site, they'll give you a section to supply text to be given to the STDIN. If you're using `input`, you need to give it text to use.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see a section called STDIN. What should I put in there?

Comment: Well, you're using `input` to supply data to `firstdestination`, so you'd give it whatever data you want entered there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230846/discussion-between-andrew-liu-and-carcigenicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an online IDE, or giving an empty input file to read input from.

I was able to re-generate your exception, when i created an empty file `empty.txt` and passed that as argument while running above code segment.

```
$ python3 main.py < empty.txt
Python Among Us

You are a Crewmate !
Where would you like to go? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vishvanath/Desktop/test/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    firstdestination = input("Where would you like to go? ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here, `main.py` contains code segment provided in question and `empty.txt` is just an empty file.

So error occurs, because your program is expecting an input, but there is none.

Comment: I am using a online IDE, that's correct, yet I'm not so sure what you mean. Could you specify what you think I should do to fix this error?

Comment: Does online IDE has option to put STDIN, if yes, that mean you can put input.

As an example, check this IDE https://www.codechef.com/ide here you can provide custom input. 

Write something in input box, it can be anything, for example "abc" and then run your code.

Comment: Yes, my online IDE has an option to put STDIN, but I'm confused on what to put inside it. If it helps, the website I use online is https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php.

Comment: I put "abc" in the STDIN area and there is no more error but somehow I can't input words into the console (weird I suppose it has to do with the IDE itself.)

Comment: @AndrewLiu  Hey, so you took user input, but then the program is  doing nothing afterwards with that information.   see, I added a new line at end of program, which is printing what user provided as input(abc) https://ideone.com/EK0F6l  

Lmk if this makes sense. 

you can click on `edit` on top left of given link and play around, with various inputs. :)